# REST Methods - Executing a "common" method call before other methods

Tags: java, android, rest, asynchronous, retrofit

I have an android app which calls to a `REST` API. The REST API is secured with `JWT`, I get the token for android when the user login to the app. The token expires in 60 minutes.

In my android app, I have different classes and they in total contains 50-60 REST calls. The android app is using `Retrofit` to connect to these REST methods. I have some methods which need to work after executing another, such methods are inside the first method's `onResponse` method.

I have a special class written called `Token` where it `set` and `get` the JWT token from variables. Every single REST call is getting the token from this class.

Anyway, since the REST is secured with `JWT`, I have to re-new the token after 50 mins. I first have to check whether the `token` variable in `Token` class is about to expire, it has a special method `whenWillExpire()` to tell me when the token will expire. If yes, then call the REST API again and get the new token.

The case is, since I can't tell on which REST call I have to re-new the token, I have to do this token expire check before `any` REST call and get the new token (if expired) before the selected REST method is called. As for an example imagine I have a method called `renew()` which checks the token and get it from server by doing a REST work. Any other REST call should run after the execution of `renew()` is done. `renew()` should run first on every REST call request. Here is an example of this method.

```
private void renew(String token) {

if(token expired){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(RestCommon.URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

GetNewToken endPoint = retrofit.create(GetNewToken.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = endPoint.getNewToken();
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
         // Good. Now we have the token. Call other methods here.
      }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}); 
}
   else
     {
       //Not expired. Call other methods.
     }
   }
```

So, how can I make sure the `renew()` runs in every REST request, before the requested method is being executed? What is the best design for this? I have like 50-60 REST methods and duplicating the above code with different names and adding other REST calls inside of it is definitely not a good pattern.

Comment: it's a design wise, i usually place all API calls in one `interface`, and i have a class that creates 1 instance of `Retrofit retrofit ...` (singleton) and use it in all calls,  and, usually i create a class (wrapper) that has a method for each API endpoint in the `interface` and in that method i call use the `retrofit` instance to call the API, i pass a `callback` as anonymous inner class in the method, it may look complicated, i can post an answer if you want. the point is in the wrapper method call, you can do all the checks you want to do, including token expiration, renewal calls ... etc

Comment: Thanks, please post answer. But I also have REST calls which "must" run one after another. Sometimes this chain is 6-7 methods long. This is also supported?

Comment: yes, you will be passing anonymous inner class as a `CallBack` in the `onResponse()` `onFail()` you can do what ever you want. i will show u a sample in minutes

Comment: actually i came to a point when token needs refresh, the suggested design supports that, but can't figure a clean way to resume the original request once token is refreshed, not sure if you are still interested in the answer .. ?

Comment: @Yazan: Actually by refresh what is meant is generating a new key. It is just another REST Call

Comment: yes, i know, but if this call is needed, you need a way to automatically resume the previous call, (the one was intended to be made) once the new token is retrieved. i will post my answer any way, and see if it helps u in any way, i can suggest a mechanism to resume the call, but it could be complex.

Answer (score 0):

Define all API endpoints:

```
public interface MyApi {
    @GET("item/{id}")
    Call<Item> getItemById(@Path("id") String id, @Header("Authorization") String auth)

    @DELETE("item/{id}")
    Call<String> deleteItemById(@Path("id") String id, @Header("Authorization") String auth)

    @POST("auth")
    Call<String> getNewToken(@Field("token") String currentToken);// or other params needed by getNewToken

    //...etc
}
```

The Wrapper class:

```
public class MyApiManager{ //?? chose other name if u want :)

    private MyApi myApi = null;
    private static MyApiManager instance = null;

    public MyApiManager getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new MyApiManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private MyApiManager(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.host.name")
        //other setting before build() ...
        .build();

        myApi = retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
    }

    //-------- General methods, like check token expired...

    private boolean checkAndGetNewToken(){
        if(token expired){
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //note here using myApi directly to avoid recursive calls for checkAndGetNewToken()
                    Response<String> response = myApi.getNewToken(token).execute();
                    Token.set(response);//update your token
                }//run()
            });
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }//token exp
        return true;
    }//checkToken

    //------ wrapper methods for each API endpoint

    public Call<Item> getItemById(String id) throws TokenExpiredException{
        checkTokenExpiration();
        return myApi.getItemById(id, "Authorization:Bearer "+Token.get());
    }

    public Call<Item> deleteItemById(String id) throws TokenExpiredException{
        checkTokenExpiration();
        return myApi.deleteItemById(id, "Authorization:Bearer "+Token.get());
    }

    public Call<Item> getNewToken(String currentToken) throws TokenExpiredException{
        checkTokenExpiration();
        return myApi.getNewToken(currentToken);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod(){
        MyApiManager.getInstance().getItem("102").enqueue(new Callback<Item>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Item> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                callApiStageB(response.getBody().getId()); //?
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                //show a toast ...
            }
        });
    }

    public void callApiStageB(String id){
        MyApiManager.getInstance().deleteItemById(id).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<String> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                //....more nested api-calls, or do anything else
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                //show a toast ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

as you can see, each call using apiManager will first check/request new token, the issue is when a new token is required, this part is handled, but how to go back and execute the original request (ex getItem()) after this step is made, because it should be made through `enqueue()` and a `CallBack`

my suggested sol for this (Thread and join()) is dirty, and i think it will throw some exception, like `NetworkOnMainThread`... hope this helps you in any way :)